# How to test code that exists on an AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that is going to be pulling messages off Kinesis and sending them to SQS. The messages have to be a certain format. How can I test something like this? The Lambda is going to contain some transformation logic but I'm not sure how to test something like this. I also need to test that the Lambda is pointing to the correct origin and target. Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Unit Tests

A Lambda is just a function so you can call it directly from your testing framework.

You can add a log inside the lambda to get some example data of the Kinesis event passed to it.

Separate the part that does the transformation from the handler boilerplate and from the code that sends to SQS.

Then you can easily test just the transformation.

#### Integration/System Tests

If you use any of the popular frameworks to deploy your stack (Serverless framework, SAM, etc.) then probably your infrastructure is described as code and it won't be that difficult to set it up and tear it down.

Then you can use the AWS SDK to to publish to Kinesis or read from SQS to make sure everything works.

I wrote a [library](https://github.com/erezrokah/aws-testing-library/) that wraps the AWS SDK and helps you write test assertions against AWS services.

Comment: would you recommend using serverless?

Comment: I use serverless framework and I think its' plugin system is a huge differentiator, but any Infrastructure as code framework should work.

Comment: plugin system? What do you mean?

Comment: https://serverless.com/plugins/

Also, any missing functionality can be added using a plugin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to test the transformation performed by the lambda, as well as the system as a whole.

The lambda code could be covered by unit tests, and the Kinesis-Lambda-SQS system could be covered with a functional end-to-end test.

For the end to end test, I don't know how your data gets into Kinesis. It might be easiest to reuse whatever you already have to automate sending specific test data into your system. You might be able to use the [Kinesis CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/index.html) to send test data.
After the test data is sent, you could use the [SQS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html) to verify that the correct SQS message was created.

Comment: would you recommend using serverless?

Comment: It depends on the task. I'm still pretty new to AWS, but in my limited experience, serverless is a tradeoff. I think you'll pay more for the processing you do, but in exchange you can get a working product much faster. For some lightweight tasks it may never be worth the developer time to architect a cheaper solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "pay more for the processing you do?"

Comment: I know of one case where someone was able to save money by converting a lambda to a microservice running in ECS. The system was taking enough traffic that the cost savings were worth spending time on the conversion.

Comment: Oh I see. You mean yeah the tradeoff is that lambdas can become more expensive than an ec2 instance depending on the processing I do.

Comment: Yes. Here's an article that goes into more depth: https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-cost/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erez's comment that you need to think about it in two ways.

## Unit testing your lambda function

- the entry point is the function itself
- the message has the same shape as one coming from Kinesis
- you can mock calls to the `aws-sdk` using, for instance, a library like `aws-sdk-mock`. In this example I'm using nodejs:

```
sqs_sendMessage_is_mocked = record => {
  AWSMock.mock('SQS', 'sendMessage', (params, callback) => {
    if (record) {
      record(params);
    }
    callback(null, { StatusCode: 200 });
  });
};
```

In tests, it could look something like this:

```
sqsParams = [];
sqs_sendMessage_is_mocked(p => sqsParams.push(p));

// invoke your function under test

// check for the expected parameters
// i.e. that the call is made a certain number of times
// or that the SQS Queue URL is being correctly set
expect(sqsParams[0].QueueUrl).to.equal('YourQueueURL');
```

### End-to-end tests

The example above doesn't touch Kinesis at all. Ideally, you want to be sure that your entire stack works. In my experience, the most useful tests for this are the ones which span multiple lambdas and check that the business rules work, rather than only one element does a very specific thing - as that's covered by unit tests.

To do this, you could:

- deploy your lambda
- push a message onto your Kinesis stream in the Cloud
- ideally, check that the whole workflow succeeds: does something pick up your SQS message and modify a dynamo table? Your test can verify that.

Since the goal of end-to-end tests is to verify that a deployed stack is functional, I'm in favour of actually deploying stacks into the cloud instead of using cloud mocking frameworks.